# undefined variable out of nowhere

Tags: matlab, matlab-guide

I have MALTAB application with GUIDE interface, in `OpeningFcn` function which is executed before GUI is made visible i have defined such global variable:

```
global P1;
P1 = [];
```

Then I have timer function executing every 2 sec, at the very beginning of this function is:

```
handles=guidata(hObj);
global P1;
```

After that two lines function makes some calculations using `P1` variable. everything was working fine for couple of hours and then suddenly I occurred this message:

> ??? Error while evaluating TimerFcn for timer 'timer-1'
>
> Undefined function or variable "P1".

and application stopped. I'd understand index out of range error or something similar but undefined variable? How is that even possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per the [documentation for `global`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/global.html):

> > To use a global within a callback, declare the global, use it, then clear the global link from the workspace. This avoids declaring the global after it has been referenced. For example,

```
cbstr = sprintf('%s, %s, %s, %s, %s', ...
   'global MY_GLOBAL',                ...
   'MY_GLOBAL = 100',                 ...
   'disp(MY_GLOBAL)',                 ...
   'MY_GLOBAL = MY_GLOBAL+1',         ...
   'clear MY_GLOBAL');

uicontrol('style', 'pushbutton', 'CallBack', cbstr, ...
   'string', 'count')
```

That being said, there typically is *never* a need to use a `global` variable. For GUIs built with GUIDE, consider using [`setappdata`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/setappdata.html) to access your variables across functions.